# underscore.js : _.where() work with first argument but not the second

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm a beginner in underscore.js, I'm trying to use _.where() to filter my data, with two parameters.

My json data.foo looks like this :

```
{"foo":[
    {"vag_id":"6","ind_id":"ade","res":"76.56","tx":"66"},
    {"vag_id":"6","ind_id":"aha","res":null,"tx":null}
...
]}
```

And my code like this :

```
ind_id = $('#fk_ind_id').val(); // return 'ade'
vag_id = $('#fk_vag_id').val(); // return 6
data_res = _.where(data.foo, { vag_id : vag_id , ind_id : ind_id });
```

and when I trying to do console.log(data_res), it equal to [] ...
When I'm use _.where() with only vag_id parameter, it work fine.

Don't see where is the problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vag_id` from the DOM Node is a number.
Changing it to a string as your data is will make it work.

Underscore's [where()](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-28) offloads into `filter()` and `matches()` which is why types matter.

Comment: Since you got your answer in before mine, [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/su6m6fpo/).

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
var data = {
    foo: [
        {"vag_id":"6","ind_id":"ade","res":"76.56","tx":"66"},
        {"vag_id":"6","ind_id":"aha","res":null,"tx":null}
    ]
};

var data_res = _.where(data.foo, { vag_id : '6' , ind_id : 'ade' });

console.log(JSON.stringify(data_res));
```

If you look at [UnderscoreJS annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html), you see that [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-28) uses [`_.matches`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-132) which issues strict equality checks (`===`). Your problem may be a mismatched type, e.g. comparing `6` (number) with `"6"` (string).